# Call phone action don't work in swift

Tags: ios, ibaction, swift3

Hello I've button action for call number , but when I used it don't call and nothing shows.

My codes under below.

```
  @IBAction func callPhone(sender: AnyObject) {
        UIApplication.shared().canOpenURL((NSURL(string: "tel://1234567890")! as URL))
    }
```

Thank You !

Comment: Remove the // characters

Comment: @Paulw11 nope dont work

Comment: Your code works. It just doesn't do what you think it does. :p

Comment: @EricD don't call Eric

Comment: Exactly what I'm saying: this code is not meant for calling. :) Look closely at which method you're using and which method the answerers are suggesting instead... They are not compatible with Swift 3 but they have the right idea.

Comment: Use ` UIApplication.shared(). openURL((NSURL(string: "tel://1234567890")! as URL))`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Proper Swift 3.0 Code

```
    if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(phoneNumber)") {
      UIApplication.shared().open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

In Swift 3.0 `NSURL` have changed to `URL`. And `sharedApplciation` changed to `shared`. Also `OpenURL` changed to `open`, they have added a bunch other parameters to the `open`method, you can pass empty dictionary in `options` and `nil` in the `completionHandler`.

Answer (score 2):

**Latest Xcode** , **Latest Swift** working codes.

use `telprompt://`  **not** `tel`

```
let myphone = "+134345345345"

 if let phone = URL(string:"telprompt://\(myphone)"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
```

Comment: This shows two buttons (Cancel & Call) - is there a way to add a header that would show the number number on top? I saw apps do that, but I am unable to find any documentation on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this answer.

```
 @IBAction func callPhone(sender: AnyObject) {

            if let url = NSURL(string: "tel://9069118117") {

            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)

       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try following code it's use to solve your problem.

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "tel://\(1234567890)") {
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}
```

Comment: when I use this code calling but gives me yellow warning that "  'openURL' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Please use openURL:options:completionHandler: instead"

Comment: Nope..I this you can use `openURL:options:completion` so might be solve your problem.

Comment: yeah need options:completion codes with your codes I think will be fine.

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper I haven't `xcode10` other wise I look into your warning :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115113/discussion-between-nimit-parekh-and-swiftdeveloper).

Answer (score 1):

please note that:

> - tel:// try to call direct the phone number;
> - telprompt:// shows you an alert to confirm call

as of iOS 10 openUrl is deprecated;

> @available(iOS, introduced: 2.0, deprecated: 10.0, message: "Please use openURL:options:completionHandler: instead")
>       open func openURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool

so i advice to use this code block to support also iOS < 9:

```
if #available(iOS 10, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(yourURL)

    // if you need completionHandler:
    //UIApplication.shared.open(yourURL, completionHandler: { (aBool) in })

    // if you need options too:
    //UIApplication.shared.open(yourURL, options: [:], completionHandler: { (aBool) in })

} else {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(number)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Info.plist, make sure you have enabled calling

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>tel</string>
    <string>sms</string>
</array>
```

The sms line may be optional, depending on your use case.

Also: Consider NOT calling `canOpenUrl` if you are calling that before.

Make sure your phone number string is formatted like this: `"tel://+12813308004"`